# Does anyone know how this visualization was made?

Tags: data-visualization

I've been tasked with implementing a visualization something like this one from the New York Times:

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/08/05/sports/olympics/the-100-meter-dash-one-race-every-medalist-ever.html?hp

Mine doesn't have to be nearly this amazing and sophisticated, but I'd like to capture at least some of the presentation elegance.  I can't find any sort of behind-the-scenes discussion of this graphic.  Does anyone have any idea how this might have been done?

Comment: What aspects are you interested in being able to reproduce? Eg, the scatterplot will be easy to reproduce, but if you want the info tags to pop up w/ mouseovers, that will require much more. Do you want to have multiple things presented together, such as appending the photos below, or the mpeg above? What programming language will you be using? Where will your graph be presented, on a webpage, powerpoint, printed in a pamphlet, etc?

Comment: @gung: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'm mostly interested in how they do that 3D panning and zooming.  The output needs to be web based.  I generally program in .NET and javascript, but I'm open to new tools as needed for making a precompiled movie and just embedding it on a web page.

Comment: the language "processing" can do interactive graphics and 3d. There are examples at both processing.org and openprocessing.org.

Comment: @Seth: since posting, I've been doing further reading and it does sound like Processing is a common tool for this kind of stuff.  Very interesting...

Comment: This strikes me as more of a programming question than one about statistical issues. As such, this question doesn't really belong here, but rather on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), where it will be more likely to attract a useful answer (although that doesn't mean it's a bad question). *Please don't cross-post* (SE strongly discourages this), if you can wait a bit, the moderators can help you migrate it. In addition, it will probably need to be edited for SO's standards, but I have no idea how to advise you to do that.

Comment: @gung: I was wondering about that, but the description here is "Q&A for statisticians, data analysts, data miners and data visualization experts", and this is a data visualization question, so I thought this was a good home for it.

Comment: It's a reasonable guess, & I may be wrong, but it sounds like you want to know 'how do I code up X?', where X just happens to be a data visualization rather than something else (eg, a hack for screwy date values). I would say that if the question is *about* the data visualization (eg, what are the pros & cons of this visualization), then it's best here, but that if it's about the *coding*, it's best on SO.